# Не могу изменить layer в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать если игрок находится за деревом - Order in layer уменьшается, в следствии чего игрок отрисовывается за деревом, то есть дерево его перекрывает. 
Вот как я это осуществить пытался: (условие выполняется, а вот код который в нем написан - нет.)

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) { 

if (coll.tag =="derevo") { 
gameObject.layer = 2; 
} 
}
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что условие выполняется, вы пробовали для начала вывести Debug.Log(...)?

Comment: Да и то, как вы пытаетесь решить данную проблему, мягко говоря, не очень решение.

Comment: Я использовал Debug.Log, все работает. Как тогда лучше решить проблему?

Comment: Что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? Это 2д игра с видом сверху? Приведите пример, от этого зависит конкретная реализация.

Answer (score 1):

От слоя `GameObject` не зависит порядок отрисовки. Если у вас 3d игра, то модели нужно физически размещать друг за другом относительно камеры, либо редактировать материалы, а если игра двухмерная, то за порядок отрисовки отвечает компонент [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) - у него есть поле `SortingLayer` и `OrderLayer`.
Общая сортировка идет по `SortingLayer` по `OrderLayer` сортируется уже внутри каждого `SortingLayer`

Comment: Вообще говоря, порядок отрисовки в 3D пространстве зависит еще и от Render Queue материала.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ну, судя по вопросу тут не тот уровень, чтобы вникать в такие детали и игра двухмерная. Но, спасибо, внёс правку:)

Comment: Все равно стоит дождаться уточнения автора, если это обычная 2д игра с видом сверху, то достаточно менять порядок отрисовки в зависимости от оси y.